# Use nginx static file cache for PHP generated images

Tags: php, nginx

I use this code in my nginx vhost configuration to cache all images, scrips etc. on my website:

```
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
  expires 1M;
  access_log off;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
```

The problem on this code is that it is not able to cache images which are generated by PHP dynamically. The base for this is that these files have not a .png or .jpg ending. They have only this structure: domain.com/images/xyz.php?id=123.

So my question is:
How can I cache these files as well? Is there any option to do that or I have to edit my PHP script?

Comment: Could you show the location that handles PHP requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can either add the caching directives to the location that handles PHP or create a location for PHP files in the images folder, add your PHP handling directives to this and put this new location above the one for general PHP requests.

```
location ~* images/(+.)\.php$ {
    # Your PHP handling directives
    [....]

    expires 1M;
    access_log off;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}
location ~* \.php$ {
    # Your PHP handling directives
    [....]
}
```